# Thymeleaf, append or replace string with document. with window.location.origin

Tags: thymeleaf

Using thymeleaf to pull an attribute from my config as such:

```
th:href="@{${@environment.getProperty('MY_PWD_RESET_LINK')}}"
```

MY_PWD_RESET_LINK in my property file is something like this, and it needs to have a redirect query param defined:

```
https://www.example.com/reset?var=12345&redirect={REDIRECT}
```

I'm trying to either replace "UPDATE_LINK" with window.location.origin value or remove the redirect queryparam and append it.

I tried this:

```
th:href="@{${@environment.getProperty('MY_PWD_RESET_LINK')}(REDIRECT='javascript:getDomain();')}"

function getDomain() {
   return window.location.origin;
}
```

But this is filling with the actual literal 'javascript:getDomain();'. How fill with value from js call?

Comment: Thymeleaf is a server side template renderer, you don't have access to client side JS since at that point Thymeleaf has already parsed the template and send as a standard HTML to the client. You could for example get the domain inside your controller via `HttpServletRequest` and pass it as a model value to the template.

Comment: Of course. Seems obvious now. Went this route and have it working.